# How to fix conflict between javascripts links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It's a strange problem may be rarely face any of you, when there are these links in a page ِِ**A** cause problems in implement javascript in page **B**.
I can not use the Enter key to move between fields if I visited the page A before page B, Also I got some trubles in css after visiting page A.
I can't remove the script links because the query wont work on modal shows without these two links in page A

**Page A**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<?php
include_once("config.php");

 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
 $search_Query = "SELECT * FROM mydate WHERE id='1' ";
 $order_no = $_REQUEST['id'];
 $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
 $search_Result = mysqli_query($conn, $search_Query);

   if($search_Result)
   {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($search_Result))
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_Result))
        {
  $conn->query("UPDATE `mydate` SET `order_no` = '$order_no',`order_date` = '$date'") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));}}}
   }


 ?>
<div id="myModal" class="modal-dialog">
<button  class = "btn btn-success" ><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok">  </span> Done</button>
  </div>
```

**Page B:**

```
<head>


    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.timepicker.css?v=0.3.3" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="include/ui-1.10.0/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<script src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src = "js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.tabs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.timepicker.js?v=0.3.3"> </script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function () {
 var focusedElement;
$(document).on('focus', 'input', function () {

            if (focusedElement == this) return; 

            focusedElement = this;

            setTimeout(function () { focusedElement.select(); }, 5); 
           });  });

      jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {

      focusable: function (el, index, selector) {

    return $(el).is('a, button, :input, [tabindex]');
     }
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', ':focusable', function (e) {


   if (e.which == 13) {

    if(!($(this).prop('nodeName')=="BUTTON"))
   e.preventDefault(); 
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#phone").blur(function () {
    var phone = $(this).val();
   if (phone == '') {}
   else{

    $.ajax({
      url: "validation.php?phonenumber="+phone

    }).done(
    function (data) {
  obj = JSON.parse(data);
   if (obj) {

   } });   
   } });  });

    var $canfocus = $(':focusable');

    var index = $canfocus.index(this) + 1;

    if (index >= $canfocus.length) index = 0;

    $canfocus.eq(index).focus();
   } });
  </script>



 <script>
 $(function() {
 $("#orderdatepicker").datepicker({
dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});

</script>
```

Comment: Please explain what "troubles" you are having. What's the exact problem?

Comment: Im using enter Key to get data using ajax, in page B but if I went to page A then enter key wont work, I must refresh website to work on Page B

Comment: *"I can not use the Enter key to move between fields if I visited the page A before page B"* - That's basically impossible unless A stores something (web storage, etc.) that B then looks for to disable using Enter. Please update your question with a [mcve] (in particular note the "Minimal", the above is way away from minimal): Two simple `HTML` files with embedded JavaScript (no PHP) that seem to replicate the problem for you at your end. That way, we can see if we can replicate the problem at our end.

Comment: code in page B is too long to write here but the main problem when use the two links:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: @VsauceCode: It's your job to reduce the problem to a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, we probably could -- **if** you reduce the problem to an [mcve]. You did read the link, right?

Comment: can i disable calling javascript links or empty cookies after leaving page

Answer (score 0):

just replaced two javascript links in page A with

```
<script src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```